# Can the if part use things other than lookaround and backreference?

Tags: regex

I am learning conditionals in regex from http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html.

It seems only mention that the if part uses  lookaround and backreference. Can the if part use things other than lookaround and backreference?

Can any expression be used for the if part?

Note that I am not restricting to a particular programming language. Just in a general setting, as the link.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would be trying to do?

Comment: Trying to understand conditionals in regex so that I will know when I can use it.

Comment: You can use `if/then/else` with `negative/positive loohahead/lookbehinds` also, here's a quick overview:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: I don't think there is anything else you can use, but you can do some pretty wicked things with negative/positive lookarounds combined with alternation (`|`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with Perl/PCRE for example you can test the existence of a capturing group *(this works in .net too)*:

```
(?(2)...|...)

(?(<group>)...|...)  # for a named capture
```

or if a recursion level has been reached:

```
(?(R)...|...)

(?(R2)...|...)
```

---

If you want, at a specific position in the string, to know if a subpattern will match later, the way is to use a lookahead as you describe it in your question, example with the strings `aaabbbccc` and `aaazzz`:

```
aaa(?(?=...ccc)bbb|zzz)
```

or

```
aaa(?(?=...ccc)(bbb|zzz))  # with a capture
```

But most of the time, you don't need to do that, a simple alternation is needed:

```
aaa(?:bbbccc|zzz)
```

or if you need to capture with the same number or name ([Branch reset feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)) `(?|...|...|...|...)`*(captures inside each alternatives have the same number)*:

```
aaa(?|(bbb)ccc|(zzz))
```

with same name:

```
aaa(?|(?<name>bbb)ccc|(?<name>zzz)) # but writing the name of the capture
                                    # a second time is not needed: 
aaa(?|(?<name>bbb)ccc|(zzz))
```

or with same name without branch reset (PCRE only):

```
(?J)aaa(?:(?<name>bbb)ccc|(?<name>zzz))
```

(The `(?J)` allows duplicate named captures)

With .net using duplicate named captures is allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I meant testing the existence of a capturing group, when I mentioned "backreference". (1) So when using a backreference as the if part, the group must always be captured before (similar to lookbehind), not captured later (similar to lookahead)? (2) So not other regex can be used as a condition in the if part?

Comment: @Tim: You can capture it before inside: A lookahead! More seriously, the branch reset feature or a simple group with an alternation may help you. Could you describe a specific case?

Comment: I meant by using a captured group only, not using lookahead, can we  still test the existence of a group somewhere ahead (not necessarily immediately ahead, i.e unlike lookahead)?

Comment: @Tim: No, you can't, the capturing group must be defined before, this is the reason why I suggest you use a simple alternation or the branch reset if you need to make any captures with same numbers/name in the two (or several) situations. Don't forget that a regex engine process a string from left to right (by default).

Comment: can you link me to study how  "the branch reset feature or a simple group with an alternation may help you", and how "use a simple alternation or the branch reset if you need to make any captures with same numbers/name in the two (or several) situations". I am not sure I understand  what branch reset is, and  what "the two (or several) situations" are.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nice answer +1 also for completion relative position e.g. `(?(-3))` but you know this :)

Comment: @Tim you're looking for reference, for branch reset see [perl re doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) then search "reset"... and here's one more read on [conditionals](http://rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html) You seem to be blazing through all regex features in a single week!!!